# Seconds to timestamp as Days:HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have a total seconds difference from two timestamps, lets say:

Table Ex

```
Timestamp_A         | Timestamp_B         | Seconds
2022-10-12 15:19:02 | 2022-11-28 15:35:38 | 4,061,796
2022-11-21 09:58:25 | 2022-11-21 09:58:27 | 2
```

I used `DATEDIFF('s', Timestamp_A, Timestamp_B)` to produce the seconds.

I want to be able to convert the seconds to something like `Days Hours:Minutes:Seconds` or at least a way to represent days (DD:HH:MM:SS).

So for these two examples, I'd have:
Table Ex

```
Timestamp_A         | Timestamp_B         | Seconds    | Converted
2022-10-12 15:19:02 | 2022-11-28 15:35:38 | 4,061,796  | 47 00:16:36
2022-11-21 09:58:25 | 2022-11-21 09:58:27 | 2          | 00 00:00:02
```

I tried messing around with `to_varchar` mixed around with `to_timestamp` but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this SQL UDF to do this. It's easier than having to complicate the SQL with the logic to calculate the formatted string:

```
create or replace function DHMS(sec int)
returns string
language sql strict immutable
as $$

    to_varchar(floor(sec/86400), '00') || ' ' 
    || to_varchar(dateadd(seconds, sec - floor(sec/86400) * 86400, '1970-01-01 00:00:00'), 'HH:MI:SS')

$$;


with T1 as
(
    select 
    COLUMN1::timestamp as Timestamp_A,
    COLUMN2::timestamp as Timestamp_B,
    COLUMN3::int as Seconds
    from (values
    ('2022-10-12 15:19:02', '2022-11-28 15:35:38', 4061796),
    ('2022-11-21 09:58:25','2022-11-21 09:58:27',  2))
)
select *, DHMS(seconds) from T1
;
```

Output:

| TIMESTAMP_A | TIMESTAMP_B | SECONDS | DHMS(SECONDS) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-12 15:19:02.000 | 2022-11-28 15:35:38.000 | 4061796 | 47 00:16:36 |
| 2022-11-21 09:58:25.000 | 2022-11-21 09:58:27.000 | 2 | 00 00:00:02 |

If you need more room for the days, just add one or more additional zeros to the `to_varchar(floor(sec/86400), '00')` part in the format string for the days.